# When should I favor JOIN instead of attribute access in singular attributes?

Tags: sql, join, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

Consider the following Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // Assume that Project has a 'name' property
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private List<Project> projects;

    @OneToOne
    private Department department;

    // Assume that Computer has a 'model' property
    @ManyToOne
    private Computer computer;

    //...
}
```

**I want to get all `Project` names for given `Employee`.**

In order to do this, I need to do a JOIN, so:

```
// JPQL query
SELECT p.name FROM Employee e JOIN e.projects p

// Criteria API equivalent (pseudo-code)
Root<Employee> emp = CriteriaQuery#from(Employee.class);
CriteriaQuery#select(emp.get(Employee_.projects).get(Project_.name));
```

And these queries are fine.

**However, I cannot do:**

```
// JPQL query
SELECT e.projects.name FROM Employee e

// Criteria API equivalent (pseudo-code)
Root<Employee> emp = CriteriaQuery#from(Employee.class);
Join<Employee, Project> empProj = emp.join(Employee_.projects);
CriteriaQuery#select(empProj.get(Project_.name));
```

As the JPA 2.0 specification forbids to use non-singular identification variable.

**However**, for singular attributes, I can access them using either JOIN or simply navigating to them using identification variable, so all of the following queries are **valid** and return the same result:

```
SELECT e.computer.model FROM Employee e
SELECT c.model FROM Employee e JOIN e.computer c

// Criteria API equivalents of the above JPQL (pseudo-code)
Root<Employee> emp = CriteriaQuery#from(Employee.class);
Join<Employee, Computer> empComp = emp.join(Employee_.computer);
CriteriaQuery#select(empComp.get(Computer_.model));

Root<Employee> emp = CriteriaQuery#from(Employee.class);
CriteriaQuery#select(emp.get(Employee_.computer).get(Computer_.model));
```

---

My questions are:
- when should I use explicit JOIN (either in JPQL or Criteria API's join(-) method)?
- what are the advantages / disadvantages of both approaches?
- is one of those considered more efficient than the other?
- if it's just a matter of style - which one would you prefer and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I just think about the type of the attribute. `e.computer` is a Computer, and I can thus call `getModel()` on it, so `e.computer.model` is OK. `e.projects` is a List, and I can't call `getName()` on a List, so `e.projects.name` is not OK. You need a join each time you need to access a member of a collection.
2. When using `e.computer.id`, a SQL join is not necessary (and not generated, at least by Hibernate), because the ID of the computer is in the employee table, as a foreign key. Using it is thus more efficient than using an explicit join. `e.computer.model` generates a SQL join, and it's just a matter of style and preference.
3. See 2.
4. I usually prefer explicit joins, because... it makes them explicit. It's also easier to transform them into left joins if needed.

Comment: Thanks JB. I just observed that without doing JOIN explicitly the generated SQL was like: `... FROM tbl1 cross join tbl2 cross join tbl3 WHERE...` while using explicit JOIN it was: `... FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3 WHERE...` which seemed quite equal to me. Didn't know if it's just a coincidence or it does make a difference in some cases.

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference. Measure it with your own database to be sure.